# wikimedia: formatting a code

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

In our projects wiki (a mediawiki wiki), I need to paste php / Js code from time to time.

I failed to find a decent, and reasonably simple way to present it as code and format it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either put the code in the `pre` tags, which won’t however highlight the syntax, or use one of the [syntax highlighting extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aSyntax_highlighting_extensions) (Wikipedia, for example, uses [SyntaxHighlight GeSHi](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSyntaxHighlight_GeSHi)).